# How to animate on finish() via ActivityOptions in Android?

Tags: android, bundle, android-animation, activity-finish

I'm working on an app that has two activities, Main and Info. The App is started with the MainActivity and when you click a button the InfoActivity slides in from the right side. When you click another button, InfoActivity shall slide out to the right side again and Main returns.

This is how I implemented the Animation and the Button Click in MainActivity:

```
buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
       Bundle mAnimate = 
          ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
           R.anim.ani1,R.anim.ani2).toBundle();

          startActivity(i,mAnimate);
            }
        });
```

I did it similar in the InfoActivity, which works fine. However, i want and need to call finish() instead of startActivity with an intent, because I have a server connection in the MainActivity which disconnects when i call startActivity.

Any Ideas how to apply an animation like that to the finish() method or other suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As explained in the [DevBytes: Window Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ho8vk61lVIU) walkthrough, you can replace your Info.class's finish() method with

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.ani2, R.anim.ani1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use

```
        ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);
```

This will finish activity after the animation

Answer (score -2):

```
Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(this,R.anim.ani1,R.anim.ani2).toBundle();
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options)
```